# How to detect dynamic text overflow in Birt

Tags: birt

In Birt I have som dynamic text elements with fixed widths. I want to compare the text that will populate the element with the width of the element to populate the element with some other value when the text is too long. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
But AFAIK if you use the PDF emitter, you could determine the needed width of a given text in a given font/size with some iText API. But you have to take into account padding, margin etc. yourself.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Unfortunately this is the answer I was afraid of. I will pursue other means of achieving my goal, but thank you for the suggestions.